# BitmapSource.Create fails sometimes

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to convert picture(JPEG , BitmapFrame) into the byte array of pixels and later to construct it back with the help of BitmapSource.Create. I am astonished becouse the same code works perfect for some pictures and fail to other. The ONLY difference i found - that at problem pictures 
pic.PixelHeight != pic.Height and pic.PixelWidth != pic.Width.  But I thought there is no problem. 
Could any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem ***could*** be due to the comparison between two different types.

1. `PixelHeight` is a `Int32` and `Height` is a `Double`.
2. Comparing `pixels` and `1/96th` inch might be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I have tryed it beforehand. I was stored this values before and use them for initialization. I have found the problem - the buffer that contains pixels sometimes corrupts - due to our marvelous math)  but beheviour of Create - is strange too - it is expected exception but it simply hangs ((